# prove $x$ is rational and $y$ is irrational then $x+y$ is irrational using contrapositive

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Hi I know this question has been asked a lot but I haven't found any proofs which is based on contrapositive. I tried this and it didnt make sense to me.

$x\in Q \wedge y\notin Q \rightarrow x+y \notin Q$

Contrapositive statement is: $x+y\in Q\rightarrow x\notin Q\wedge y\in Q$

Which doesnt make sense to me. But I feel that I might have also got the contrapositive wrong.

Comment: Since your are new. When someone give you an answer and that you think that the answer is good and correct you can can approve the question to give some credit to the answer. –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your contraposition is wrong; it should be $\lor$ and not $\land$ by De Morgan's laws. Either way, contraposition isn't quite the best way to prove the fact, because $x+y$ being rational does not rule out the possibility that both $x,y$ are irrational, and you would eventually repeat the more direct contradiction proof.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $x+y \in \mathbb{Q} $ then
(because a sum of rational is rational $\frac{p}{q} +\frac{p'}{q' }=\frac{ pq'+p'q}{qq'}$)

$x+y-x\in\mathbb{Q}$ then $y\in\mathbb{Q}$ .